# How can I execute multiple Cypher queries simultaneously in the Memgraph Lab editor?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm using Memgraph Lab for querying my graph database. Sometimes, I need to execute multiple Cypher queries in one go. How can I run multiple queries at once in the Memgraph Lab editor?
When I run this:

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name = 'Alice' RETURN n
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.age > 25 RETURN n
```

I get an error:

```
Query failed: MATCH can't be put after RETURN clause or after an update.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delimiter for queries is `;`, when you specify multiple queries in the editor and separate them by `;`, Memgraph Lab will execute each of those queries serially and all in separated transactions. Just add the to the end of lines

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name = 'Alice' RETURN n;
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.age > 25 RETURN n;
```

Answer (score 1):

So long as the return types are the same, in openCypher you should be able to use a `UNION` to combine these two

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name = 'Alice' RETURN n
UNION
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.age > 25 RETURN n
```

you could also look at using an `OR`

```
MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name = 'Alice' OR n.age > 25 
RETURN n
```